# Is there anyway to take a screenshot of the entire console window?

Tags: python, console, pycharm

I'm working on some analysis, and I'm printing things to the console in order to analyze them.
[image: Stacks Picture]

This scrolls on for anywhere from 10-30 "moves". Is there any way to somehow screenshot the entire console? What I'm currently doing is splitting it into 5+ screenshots, then stacking them all vertically in a word document. I know I could write something to essentially turn it all into HTML, but that isn't what I'm looking for. Just hoping to be able to screenshot the entire console window. (I use PyCharm for development, although I'm not sure if there is a IDE specific solution, or just an overall one)
I would just copy-paste it, but I'm using color-codes ANSI sequences for the coloring, and its not wanting to paste properly.

Comment: As you already capturing the screenshot, the easier way is to concatenate the images across the vertical axis using OpenCV.

Comment: The goal is to only have to take a single screenshot, instead of taking multiple, which involves scrolling, taking a screenshot, saving the image, and repeating. I'm doing this for hours at a time, and therefore being able to do it in one screenshot would turn 5 hours of work into 1 hour. @ashtav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how effective it will for you. But

> Picpack

a third part software works fine for me:-
And there a few other options too which you can try... Because In you're case such Application will be a lot of helpful.

Other software which You can use for this part:-

> Apowersoft Screen Capture Pro
>
> Blockquote

Snagit